# WSO2 UES service registering method

Tags: wso2

I am getting my hands on WSO2 UES server. I wrote an jaggery dashboard app and working fine. When porting the jaggery app to another UES server i have to manually register for the SAML sso. After manually configuring i am able to access. Is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure to automate this. Go to /repository/conf/ and in the file sso-idp-config.xml add following configuration.

```
    <ServiceProvider>
        <Issuer>MyApp</Issuer>
        <AssertionConsumerService>http://x.x.x.x:9763/MyApp/sso.jag</AssertionConsumerService>
        <CustomLoginPage>ssoApp/login_processor.jag</CustomLoginPage>
    </ServiceProvider>
```

But this is not recommended at all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I know the security issue. Just for curiosity.